# About opencv4android example 15-puzzle

Tags: android, opencv

I've curtailed the code of 15-puzzle, which is provided as an example by opencv4android. Now the shortend code runs well in its orginal documentary position, but after I copied them to a helloworld project set up elsewhere, the program crashes with Logcat putting up NoClassFoundDefError of the MainActivity. I've tried to look into manifest.xml but still can't figure out the cause of the problem. Can you help me? Thank you!

Below is my code:

1.puzzle15Activity

```
package org.opencv.samples.puzzle15;
import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.text.method.*;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.*;


public class puzzle15Activity extends Activity
{

SampleCvViewBase mView=null;
private BaseLoaderCallback  mOpenCVCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) 
{
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                mView=new SampleCvViewBase(mAppContext);
                setContentView(mView);


            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
        }

    }
};


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_2,this,mOpenCVCallBack);

}
```

}

2.SampleCvViewBase

```
package org.opencv.samples.puzzle15;

import java.util.List;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import org.opencv.core.*;
import org.opencv.calib3d.Calib3d;

class SampleCvViewBase extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Runnable {


int t;
Scalar s=new Scalar(100,100,100,100);
Scalar s1=new Scalar(1);
Scalar s2=new Scalar(100);
byte []t1={1,0,0,1};
int []t2={5,4,3,2};
int[] t3;



Mat mrgba;
Mat m1,m2,m3;
public int[] list={1,2,3};

@Override
public SampleCvViewBase(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mrgba=new Mat(4,4,CvType.CV_16S,s);
    mrgba.create(4,4,CvType.CV_8UC(15));
    m1=new Mat(2,2,CvType.CV_8U,s1);
    m2=new Mat(2,2,CvType.CV_32S,s2);
    m3=new Mat(2,2,CvType.CV_32S,s2);
    m1.put(0,0,t1);
    m2.put(0,0,t2);
    t3=new int[4];
    m2.get(0,0,t3);
    t3[1]=200;
    m2.put(0,0,t3);
    m2.copyTo(m3);


}

public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder _holder, int format, int width, int height) {

}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

      }

public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }

public void run() {}

}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying...on myself...Can someone provide me with a complete opencv setup frame that is working?...

Comment: I'm not aware of that one. May be others will do.

Answer (score 0):

OK, now I found some reason behind this. The classes in bin are not compiled.